# Как передать в функцию несколько параметров через пробел?

Tags: python

Хочу сделать такую функцию:

```
def f(???):
   print(???)
f(1 2 3 4 5)
```

Мне нужно сделать как-то это не через запятые, а именно через пробел. Помогите

Comment: Зачем через пробел? Есть синтаксис языка, оптимальный для него. В чем смысл такого действия? (Это не проблема ХY?)

Comment: я делаю дискорд бота, и там юзер не будет писать слова через ",". Мне нужно понять, как сделать это через пробел

Comment: Как и думал, это проблема ХY. Совет ниже (оформил ответом, чтобы код включить), если он решает проблему, то советую перечитать хоть начальные главы учебника (я серьёзно - сильно упростит программирование).

Comment: Если ответы были полезны, их можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Ответ, который полностью решил задачу - принять (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам ввод от user нужен, то решите проблему на уровне ввода.

Например,

```
    # Ввод строки, разделение её по пробелу и распаковка её в отдельные параметры
    a, b = input().split()
    # Вызов функции с, если надо, например, преобразованием строковых значений в целые
    f (int(a), int (b))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(cmd, *args):
    print(cmd) 
    print(args) 

question = input ()
f(*(question.split()))
```